# Using ReactiveCommand and WhenAny in inherited classes

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactiveui

Consider using inheritance with ReactiveUI.
I have base ViewModel class with DoSomethingCommand. ‘CanExecute’ for this command depends on property Prop1

```
public class A : ReactiveObject
{
    public int Prop1 { get {...} set {...} }
    public ReactiveCommand DoSomethingCommand { get; private set; }

    public A()
    {
        IObservable<bool> canDoSomething = this.WhenAny(vm => vm.Prop1, p1 => CanDoSomething());
        DoSomethingCommand = new ReactiveCommand(canDoSomething);
        DoSomethingCommand.Subscribe(x => DoSomething());
    }

    protected virtual bool CanDoSomething()
    {
        return ...
    }
}
```

In inherited class the ‘CanExecute’ for this command depends additionally on property Prop2

```
public class B : A
{
    public int Prop2 { get {...} set {...} }

    public B()
    {
        //Senseless code. For explanation only
        IObservable<bool> canDeleteExecute = this.WhenAny(vm => vm.Prop1, vm => vm.Prop2, (p1, p2) => CanDoSomething());
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to create command and make ‘CanExecute’ dependent on properties from base and inherited classes?
Of course, I want inherited classes shouldn’t change when ‘CanExecute’ in base class become additionally depend on AnotherProp property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written extension class for WhenAny. It's much more to do for making it like WhenAny in ReactiveUI, but enough for me now. First, look at usage:

```
public class A : ReactiveObject
{
    public A()
    {
        //Using almost like WhenAny from ReactiveUI
        CanExecuteObservable = this.WhenAny(() => AProp, CanExecute);
        Command = new ReactiveCommand(CanExecuteObservable);
        Command.Subscribe(x => Execute());
    }

    protected CanExecuteObservable CanExecuteObservable { get; private set; }
    public ReactiveCommand Command { get; private set; }

    protected virtual bool CanExecute()
    {
        return AProp > 10;
    }

    private int aProp = 10;
    public int AProp { get { return aProp; } set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.AProp, value); } }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        //Add one more property dependency for CanExecute
        CanExecuteObservable.AddProperties(() => BProp);
    }

    private int bProp = 10;
    public int BProp { get { return bProp; } set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.BProp, value); } }

    protected override bool CanExecute()
    {
        return base.CanExecute() && BProp > 100;
    }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public static class WhenAnyExtensions
{
    public static CanExecuteObservable WhenAny(this IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged obj,
        IEnumerable<Expression<Func<object>>> expressions, Func<bool> func)
    {
        return new CanExecuteObservable(obj, expressions, func);
    }

    public static CanExecuteObservable WhenAny(this IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged obj, Expression<Func<object>> property1, Func<bool> func)
    {
        return obj.WhenAny(new[] { property1 }, func);
    }

    public static CanExecuteObservable WhenAny(this IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged obj, Expression<Func<object>> property1, Expression<Func<object>> property2, Func<bool> func)
    {
        return obj.WhenAny(new[] { property1, property2 }, func);
    }

    //etc...
}

public class CanExecuteObservable : IObservable<bool>
{
    internal CanExecuteObservable(IReactiveNotifyPropertyChanged obj,
        IEnumerable<Expression<Func<object>>> expressions, Func<bool> func)
    {
        this.func = func;
        AddProperties(expressions);
        obj
            .Changed
            .Where(oc => propertyNames.Any(propertyName => propertyName == oc.PropertyName))
            .Subscribe(oc => Fire());
    }

    private readonly List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>();
    private readonly Func<bool> func;

    public void AddProperties(IEnumerable<Expression<Func<object>>> expressions)
    {
        foreach (var expression in expressions)
        {
            string propertyName = ReflectionHelper.GetPropertyNameFromExpression(expression);
            propertyNames.Add(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public void AddProperties(Expression<Func<object>> property1) { AddProperties(new[] { property1 }); }
    public void AddProperties(Expression<Func<object>> property1, Expression<Func<object>> property2) { AddProperties(new[] { property1, property2 }); }
    //etc...

    public void Clear()
    {
        propertyNames.Clear();
    }

    private readonly Subject<bool> subject = new Subject<bool>();

    private void Fire()
    {
        subject.OnNext(func());
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<bool> observer)
    {
        return subject.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

And uninteresting, in this context, helper class for getting property name from expression:

```
public class ReflectionHelper
{
    public static string GetPropertyNameFromExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property) 
    {
        var lambda = (LambdaExpression)property;
        MemberExpression memberExpression;

        if (lambda.Body is UnaryExpression) 
        {
            var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)lambda.Body;
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        } 
        else 
        {
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)lambda.Body;
        }
        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a registration function in my base class to register
observables using CombineLatest

```
    property IObservable<bool> CanDo;

    public IObservable<bool> RegisterCanDo( IObservable<bool> toRegister ){
            if ( CanDo == null ){
                    CanDo = toRegister;
            }else{
                    Cando = CanDo.CombineLatest(toRegister, (a,b) => a && b);
            }

    }
```

So now anywhere you have an observable that you want to make part of your
CanDo chain you just add it with RegisterCanDo

```
    public class B : A
    {
        public int Prop2 { get {...} set {...} }

        public B()
        {
            //Senseless code. For explanation only
            IObservable<bool> canDeleteExecute = this.WhenAny(vm => vm.Prop1, vm => vm.Prop2, (p1, p2) => CanDoSomething());
            RegisterCanDo(canDeleteExecute);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but there's no way to unregister a `CanDo` and so with the `CombineLatest` you're potentially making sure that the `CanDo` always remains false. Perhaps `RegisterCanDo` needs to return `IDisposable` and you need a mechanism to manage the internal `CanDo` state?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you wanted above. However be careful with threading. I haven't made it threadsafe for adding and removing message sources on combining values.

You can add and remove message sources to the Concentrator object and you can observe the Concentrator for the true value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

public class BoolObservableConcentrator : IObservable<bool>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<IObservable<bool>, bool> dict = new Dictionary<IObservable<bool>, bool>();

    public IDisposable Register(IObservable<bool> observable)
    {
        dict.Add(observable, false);
        var d = observable.Subscribe(value =>
        {
            dict[observable] = value;
            Fire();
        });
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            d.Dispose();
            dict.Remove(observable);
            Fire();
        });
    }

    private readonly Subject<bool> subject = new Subject<bool>();

    private void Fire()
    {
        subject.OnNext(dict.Values.All(x => x));
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<bool> observer)
    {
        return subject.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

And test for it:

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var s0 = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);
        var s1 = new BehaviorSubject<bool>(false);

        bool l = false;

        var c = new BoolObservableConcetrator();

        var r0 = c.RegisterSource(s0);
        var r1 = c.RegisterSource(s1);

        var s = c.Subscribe(v => l = v);

        Assert.AreEqual(false, l);

        s0.OnNext(true);
        Assert.AreEqual(false, l);

        s1.OnNext(true);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, l);

        s0.OnNext(false);
        Assert.AreEqual(false, l);

        // Removing one of the message sources should update the result
        r0.Dispose();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, l);
    }
}
```

Comment: The original post can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13152784/1

Comment: @elshev thanks for the rewrite to c#. I'm constantly switching between vb.net and c# depending on the code base. I'm not even sure why MS bothers with VB.net as for all purposes it is identical to c# hence i didn't realize id posted vb.net code till id submitted ;)

Comment: But you removed my warning about thread safety. I haven't checked the code fire combinelatest but id guess they do some sort of locking on the buffer which the above code doesn't

Comment: Thanks a lot @bradgonesurfing. It's good solution but I tried it and find out two disadvantages.

1. Every inheritor must specify CanExecute in every Register method

2. The initial state of non-firing observable is unknown(false in your example). So the inheritor must to worry about it. Elsewhere dict.Values.All(x => x) will return false until all observables fire.

Below I've written solution that only collects property dependencies. CanExecute specified only once in base class.

Comment: Actually they are not false but I had to init the dict to fields to something. If the subjects are BehaviourSubjects they will fire immediately on subscription with the correct current value. Note that I do not subscribe to the BoolObservableConcentrator until all the sources are registered and by this time it is stable. I don't understand what you mean about having every inheritor specifying CanExecute. This is a utility class and makes no assumptions about how your classes that use it implement inheritence or not.

Comment: And the OP also asked that sources can be unregistered otherwise WhenAny from ReactiveUI or CombineLatest from core reactive would do the trick with no troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just replace it in the derived constructor:

**Update**: Here's a version that takes the original into consideration

```
public class A
{
    public ReactiveCommand SomeCommand { get; protected set; }

    public A()
    {
        SomeCommand = new ReactiveCommand(this.WhenAny(x => x.SomeProp, ...));
    }
}


public class B : A
{
    public A()
    {
        var newWhenAny = this.WhenAny(x => x.SomeOtherProp, ...);

        var canExecute = SomeCommand == null ?
            newWhenAny :
            SomeCommand.CanExecuteObservable.CombineLatest(newWhenAny,(oldCommand, whenAny) => oldCommand && whenAny);

        SomeCommand = new ReactiveCommand(canExecute);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I want: 
1. SomeCommand depends on SomeProp and SomeOtherProp simultaneously.
2. Class B wouldn't bother if SomeCommand became depend on SomeProp2, SomeProp3 etc. in class A